# How to define homogeneous functions that respect Euler's theorem of homogeneous functions?

Tags: function-construction, symbolic, argument-patterns, attributes, upvalues

A homogeneous function of degree $k$ is defined as a function that observes the following specification rule:

> $f(a x_1, a x_2, ..., a x_n) = a^k f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$

(see Wikipedia entry, [Positive homogeneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function))

Also, it satisfies the Euler homogeneous function theorem; i.e

> $k f= x_1f_{x_1}+x_2f_{x_2}+...+x_nf_{x_n}$

where $f_{(.)}$ denotes a partial derivative.

Finally, the derivative of a homogeneous function is also a homogeneous function with a degree of homogeneity equal to the degree of homogeneity of the initial function minus one.

What is a *proper* idiomatic way to define homogeneous functions that allows seamless symbolic as well as numeric manipulation?

*(some) **Examples of desired behavior*** *(assume $g(y, z)$ is homogeneous of degree $k$)*

```
 In[1]: g[b y, b z]
Out[1]: b^k g[y, z]
```

,

```
In[2]: g[y b, b z]/.b->1/z
Out[2]: (1/z)^k g[y/z, 1]
```

,

```
 In[3]: D[g[y b, z b], b]
Out[3]: k g[y, z]
```

Comment: This will replicate the behavior, but i don't know if this is what you are looking for: `Attributes[f]=HoldAll;
f[x_*a_:1,x_*b_:1]:=x^k f[a,b];
f/:k*f[a_,b_]:=a*Derivative[1,0,0,0][f][a,b]+b*Derivative[0,1,0,0][f][a,b];`

Comment: Take a look at upvalues in Mathematica. This should explain what you can do with custom assignments in Mathematica, even if certain symbols like `D` are protected.

Comment: @ruddi02: yep, `HoldAll` does the trick in order to achieve the definition of a homogeneous function i.e $f(a x, a y)=a^k f(x,y)$ but `In[1]: f[x,x]` spits out a _RecursionLimit_ error. Also, defining the upvalue wrt _f_ certainty produces the desired result as far as _Euler_'s theorem is concerned but `In[2]: D[g[y b, z b], b]` still doesn't evaluate to k g[y, z] as it should. Thanks for the input!

Comment: @Wizard: I have looked at upvalues (I even used the tag for it) and the reason I posted is that I cannot seem to make it work. Will have another go at it later... . Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Update 1: Answer restructured and code modified to address OP's comments.*

*Update 2: Code extended to account for the cases mentioned in OP's comments (see Definition 2 in commented line in the code).*

*Update 3: Code extended to account for cases with powers, such as `g[x^2, x^3]`.*

---

*This only addresses the first property of OP's question:*

> $f(a x_1, a x_2, ..., a x_n) = a^k f(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$

---

**Introduction**

`makeHomogeneous[f, k]` defines for a symbol `f` a downvalue that encodes the homogeneity of degree `k`. Some particular features of the code are:

*1)* The homogeneity property applies for any number of arguments passed to `f`.

*2)* The downvalue for homogeneity always fires first, even if other downvalues were defined previously.

*3)* The degree `k` needs to be given as a symbol or a positive integer.

*4)* Exponents of powers must be nonnegative integers or symbols for the homogeneity property to fire.

**Code**

```
makeHomogeneous[fun_Symbol, k : (_Integer?NonNegative | _Symbol)] :=
    Module[{downvalues = DownValues[fun]},

        DownValues[fun] = {};

        (** Definition 1 **)

        fun[args : HoldPattern[Times[__]] ..] := Module[
            {list = {args}, fact, x, res, temp, hold},

            temp = Replace[list, 
               Power[a_, expn_] /; MatchQ[expn, _Integer?NonNegative | _Symbol] :> 
                      a hold[Power[a, expn - 1]], {2}];

            fact = MaximalBy[GatherBy[Join @@ List @@@ temp, Identity], Length];
            If[Length[fact[[1]]] == Length[list],
                 fact = Times @@ fact;
                 x = Divide[list, fact];
                 res = (First@ fact)^k fun @@ x /. hold -> Identity,
                 res = $Failed
            ];

            res /; res =!= $Failed

        ];

        (** Definition 2 **)

        fun[args___] := Block[{$tried = True}, 
            Module[{list = {args}, a, temp, hold},

                temp = Replace[list,
                   Power[x_, expn_] /; MatchQ[expn, _Integer?NonNegative | _Symbol] :> 
                   x hold[Power[x, expn - 1]],
                   {1}
                ];

                fun[Sequence @@ (a temp)] /. {a -> 1, hold -> Identity}
            ]

        ] /; ! TrueQ[$tried];


        AppendTo[DownValues[fun], downvalues];

    ];
```

**Usage**

```
makeHomogeneous[g, k]

g[a x, a y]
(* a^k g[x, y] *)

g[a x, x y]
(* x^k g[a, y] *)

g[a x, a x]
(* (a x)^k g[1, 1] *)

g[a x, a y b]
(* a^k g[x, b y] *)

g[5 x, 5 x y, 5 x y z]
(* 5^k x^k g[1, y, y z] *)

(* Update 2 *)

g[x, x]
(* x^k g[1, 1] *)

g[x, x y]
(* x^k g[1, y] *)

g[x, a x, x y, x y z]
(* x^k g[1, a, y, y z] *)

(* Update 3 *)

g[x, x^2]
(* x^k g[1, x] *)

g[a x, a x^p, a x^q]
(* (a x)^k g[1, x^(-1 + p), x^(-1 + q)] *)

g[x^l y^m, x^p y^q]
(* (x y)^k g[x^(-1 + l) y^(-1 + m), x^(-1 + p) y^(-1 + q)] *)
```

**Comments**

> *1)* The homogeneity property applies for any number of arguments passed to `f`.

In case it is preferable to avoid this flexibility, the syntax of `makeHomogeneous` and its code could be modified as follows:

```
makeHomogeneous[{fun_Symbol, nbArgs_Integer?NonNegative}, 
                 k : (_Integer?NonNegative | _Symbol)] :=
    Module[{downvalues = DownValues[fun]},

        DownValues[fun] = {};

        With[{n = nbArgs},
          fun[args : Repeated[HoldPattern[Times[__]], {n}]] := ....
        ];

        With[{n = nbArgs},
          fun[args : Repeated[_, {n}]] := ...
        ];

        AppendTo[DownValues[fun], downvalues];

    ];
```

> *2)* The downvalue for homogeneity always fires first, even if other downvalues were defined previously.

Here is an example:

```
g[x_, y_, z_, u_] := x y z u (* new downvalue after homogeneity definition above *)
g[5 x, 5 y, 5 z, 5 u]
(* 5^k u x y z *) (* homogeneity fires first *)
(* alternative would result in: 625 x y z *)

h[x_, y_] := x^6 y (* downvalue before homogeneity definition *)
h[x_, y_, z_] := x y^3 z^3 (* downvalue for three arguments *)

makeHomogeneous[h, p]

h[a x, a y]
(* a^p x^6 y *) (* homogeneity fires first *)
(* alternative would result in: a^7 x^6 y *)

h[2 x, 2 y, 2 z]
(* 2^p x y^3 z^3 *) (* homogeneity fires first *)
(* alternative would result in: 128 x y z *)
```

In case this behavior is not needed, the `AppendTo` in the code could be changed to `PrependTo`. This would modify the evaluations of `h` only.

> *3)* The degree `k` needs to be given as a symbol or a positive integer.

The pattern test `(_Integer?NonNegative | _Symbol)` can be removed for complete flexibility. In case constraints are needed with more working cases, one could define a function `degreeQ` and test it on `k` with `k_?degreeQ`. Simple definitions for this symbol could be for instance:

```
degreeQ[_?Internal`RealValuedNumericQ] := True;
degreeQ[_Symbol] := True;
degreeQ[args: HoldPattern[Times[__]]] := And @@ degreeQ /@ List @@ args;
(* ... other definitions ... *)
degreeQ[_] := False;
```

> *4)* Exponents of powers must be nonnegative integers or symbols for the homogeneity property to fire.

Here also, the pattern `MatchQ[expn, _Integer?NonNegative | _Symbol]` can be removed for more flexibility, and a function be added if necessary. This modification may yield recursion errors, which can be avoided by using the `Block` trick of the second definition on the first one as well.

Comment: stuff that don't work: 1. `In[1]:= g[x,x]` returns `Out[1]:= g[x,x]` instead of the correct `Out[1']:= x^k g[1,1]` 2. `In[2]:= D[g[a x, a x], a]` returns `Out[2]:= k (a x)^(k-1) g[1,1]` instead of the correct `Out[2']:= k g[x,y]`. I guess that (1) is trivial to resolve and I understand that you have not tackled the issues with D[]. In any case, I'll consider the answer as correct and try to address the remaining shortcomings of the code myself. Thanx @Xavier

Comment: just for history's sake, a fast solution to issue (1) above is to interject this: `fun[args : HoldPattern[_] ..] := 
 Module[{list = {args}, union, bool, seq, res, a},
  union = Union[list];
  bool = ((union =!= {1}) && (Length[union] == 1) && (Length[list] > 
       1));
  If[bool === True,
   seq = Sequence @@ (a list);
   res = fun[seq];
   res = res /. a -> 1,
   res = $Failed
   ];
  res /; res =!= $Failed
  
  ];` between the original def of `fun[]` and the `AppendTo[]` in `makeHomogeneous[]`

Comment: @user42582 Thanks for the accept. I have updated the code to account for case (1) and related. Inputs like `g[x, x]` and `g[x, a x]` now works. Note that the code is not yet complete, as the homogeneity property will not apply for things like `g[x, x^2]`. This should probably require a third definition in the code, or perhaps it could be mixed with definition 2 with additional checks and processing on `args`.

Comment: @user42582 I've updated my answer to account for the above-mentioned missing cases.